# how to create new upload_to for FileField folder from views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**in models.py,**

```
class Files(models.Model):
    File = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/")
```

**in my views.py, all works perfectly when i remove the 3rd line**

```
file = Files(File=f)
file.File.upload_to('Media/')
file.save()
```

**Question** is.

I want to create new `upload_to` Folder from views.py only. is it even POSSIBLE ?
*I know the instance function method of creating Folder used in models.py, i dont want to use it*

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of the file, and thus work with:

```
from django.conf import settings
from os.path import join as pathjoin

file = Files(File=f)
old_path = car.photo.path
file.File.name = f'Media/{file.File.name}'
new_path = pathjoin(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file.File.name)
rename(path, new_path)
file.save()
```

We thus first construct a `Files` object with `f` as `File`, then we check the path, create a new name, and then move the file to the new directory and update the `Files` object in the database.

You can do this in bulk by enumerating over the `Files` items and set the file as described in the answer. Instead of saving the object directly, you can collect these in a list and perform a [**`.bulk_update(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update):

```
from django.conf import settings
from os.path import join as pathjoin

files = list(Files.objects.all())
for file in files:
    old_path = car.photo.path
    file.File.name = f'Media/{file.File.name}'
    new_path = pathjoin(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, file.File.name)
    rename(path, new_path)
Files.objects.bulk_update(files, ['File'])
```

Comment: Thanks Man, But what if I wanted to get all querysets like `all_files = Files.objects.all()` and then loop it `for item in data:` `print(item.File.url)` ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what would be the problem, you can enumerate with `for file in Files.objects.all()` and set the file as described in the answer. Instead of saving the object directly, you can collect these in a list and perform a `.bulk_update(...)`.

Comment: I elaborated here https://stackoverflow.com/q/70115583/14437947

Comment: @Verma: can't you work with the first codefragment, where you use `file.File.name = f'{request.user.username}/{new_thread.pk}'` instead of the `file.File.name = f'Media/{file.File.name}'`?