# How to upload Files in django to your desired Folder

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

**model.py**

```py
class Thread(models.Model):
    user = models.Foreignkey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Media = models.ManyToManyField("Files", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Files(models.Model):
    File = models.FileField(upload_to="thisFolderDoesNotMatter/")
```

**in forms.py**

```py
class ThreadForm(ModelForm):
    Files_Form_Label = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}))

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ("Title",)
```

**in views.py**

```py
from django.views import View
class NewThread(View):
    template_name = 'Thread/New.html'
    def get(self, request, id):
        return render(request, self.template_name, context={
           'form':ThreadForm(),
           'data':Thread.objects.get(pk=id)
        })


    def post(self, request):
        form_data = ThreadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        all_files = request.FILES.getlist('File_Form_Label')
        if form_data.is_valid():
            new_thread = form_data.save(commit=False)
            new_thread.user = request.user
            new_thread.save()
            for f in all_files:
                file = Files(File=f)

                # here is the problem that i want to upload this file in 
                # MEDIAROOT/request.user.username/new_thread.id/
                # ANY method to do this ?

                file.save()
                new_thread.Media.add(file)
            new_thread.save()
            return HTTPResponse('SUCCESSFULL')
```

I know the instance method for ManyToOneField but don't know how to use it for ManyToManyField.

I know the instance method for ManyToOneField but don't know how to use it for ManyToManyField.